# Emacs scheme (scheme-mode) indentation

Tags: emacs, scheme, indentation, auto-indent

By default, scheme mode in Emacs formats code using one space indentation:

```
(string-append
 "foo "
 "bar "
 "baz")
```

I want it to be at least two spaces, i.e.:

```
(string-append
  "foo "
  "bar "
  "baz")
```

For most modes in Emacs this is pretty easy to change, but I haven't figured out how to do it for scheme. I've looked at the source code for scheme.el as well, and while there is logic in there for doing all kinds of fancy alignments I haven't found a simple way of customizing the "standard indent".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set `lisp-indent-offset` to 2, but you almost certainly don't want to do this, unless you really know what you're doing.

Lisp-style languages adhere to a slightly different indentation philosophy than other languages. When the first element of an S-expression is alone after the open parenthesis, the convention is to line up the remaining elements to start in the same column:

```
(first-item
 second-item
 third-item fourth-item fifth-item
 sixth-item)
```

When the second element is on the same line with the first one, the convention is to align the following elements the second one:

```
(first-item second-item
            third-item fourth-item fifth-item
            sixth-item)
```

This convention applies to sexps that are not special forms, including function calls such as the call to `string-append`. Special forms, sexps that are specially interpreted by the evaluator and the compiler, follow slightly different indentation. A form that provides expressions to evaluate will be indented with two spaces:

```lisp
(lambda (value)
  (display value)
  (send-eof))
```

To an experienced Lisper, two spaces subtly denote that the expression is a special form whose two-space-indented subforms will be evaluated in sequence. When you create your own special forms using `define-syntax` or `defmacro`, you can tell Emacs to indent their subforms the same way:

```lisp
;; define a CL-style `unless` macro...
(defmacro unless (test &rest forms)
  `(or ,test (progn ,@forms)))

;; ...and tell emacs to indent its body forms with two spaces
;; (unless (= value 0)
;;   (display value)
;;   (send-eof))
(put 'unless 'lisp-indent-function 2)
```

Changing the indentation level would send the wrong signal to the reader about what is going on, detracting from your code. If you don't like how Emacs indents your call to `string-append`, I suggest to switch to the second form, which will automatically indent the strings further to the right:

```lisp
(string-append "foo "
               "bar "
               "baz")
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I tested your lambda example and then it indents with two spaces. Looks like I need to change my habits (which are mostly clojure based so far).

Comment: Another observation; when creating java/scheme hybrids using Kawa (e.g. Android apps), both of the standard indentation forms of scheme looks really bad, due.to.really.long.statements. This leads to either one-space indents, or that most of the left part of the editor window is emply whitespace. Doesn't look like something that would be easy to fix based on the current scheme conventions.

Comment: I don't have experience with Kawa and similar, but I believe the conventional answer is to live with the one-space indents in that case. At that point it's probably a good idea to take a look at other people's source code to find out what's accepted as best practice in that particular community.

Comment: Yes, I'me experimenting with rainbow delimiters and color-boxing of s-expressions now to make it prettier without messing with the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Variety in indentation styles is a source of problems.  So while Emacs modes generally try to support most existing indentation styles, they don't necessarily make it easy to use a different style, since that would encourage people to invent new styles.  You'll generally be better off learning to live with the "standard" indentation style: that will help you read other people's code and help other people read your code.